# Getting an error when i run this pagination page demo in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, pagination

```
<?php
 include("include/db.inc.php");

  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp");
  $nr = mysql_num_rows($sql);

 if(isset($_GET['page'])){
  $pn = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_GET['page']);
 }else{
  $pn = 1;
 }

$itemPerPage = 10;
$lastPage = ceil($nr/$itemPerPage);
if($pn < 1){
$pn = 1;
}elseif($pn > $lastPage){
$pn = $lastPage;
}

$centerPage = '';
$sub1 = $pn - 1;
$sub2 = $pn - 2;
$add1 = $pn + 1;
$add2 = $pn + 2;

if($pn == 1){
$centerPage .= '&nbsp;<span class="pagNumActive">'. $pn .'</span>&nbsp;';
$centerPage .= '&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='. $add1 .'">'. $add1 .'</a>&nbsp;';
}elseif($pn == $lastPage){
$centerPage .= '&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='. $sub1 .'">'. $sub1 .'</a>&nbsp;';
$centerPage .= '&nbsp;<span class="pagNumActive">'. $pn .'</span>&nbsp;';
}elseif($pn == 2 && $pn < ($lastPage - 1)){
$centerPage .= '&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='. $sub2 .'">'. $sub2 .'</a>&nbsp;';
$centerPage .= '&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='. $sub1 .'">'. $sub1 .'</a>&nbsp;';
$centerPage .= '&nbsp;<span class="pagNumActive">'. $pn .'</span>&nbsp;';
$centerPage .= '&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='. $add1 .'">'. $add1 .'</a>&nbsp;';
$centerPage .= '&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='. $add2 .'">'. $add2 .'</a>&nbsp;';
}elseif($pn > 1 && $pn < $lastPage){
$centerPage .= '&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='. $sub1 .'">'. $sub1 .'</a>&nbsp;';
$centerPage .= '&nbsp;<span class="pagNumActive">'. $pn .'</span>&nbsp;';
$centerPage .= '&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='. $add1 .'">'. $add1 .'</a>&nbsp;';
}

$paginationDisplay = '';
if($lastPage != '1'){
$paginationDisplay .= 'Page <strong>'.$pn.'</strong> of '.$lastPage.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
if($pn != 1){
    $previous = $pn - 1;
    $paginationDisplay .= '&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page=1">First</a> ';
    $paginationDisplay .= '&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$previous.'">Back</a>';
}
$paginationDisplay .= '<span class="paginationNumbers">'.$centerPage.'</span>';
if($pn != $lastPage){
    $nextPage = $pn+1;
    $paginationDisplay .= '&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$nextPage.'">Next</a>';
    $paginationDisplay .= '&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$lastPage.'">Last</a> ';
}
 }
```

**I got error here whenever i try to run this demo page...** Here are the error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT0,10' at line 1
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in G:\Backup\US\root\php-db\dashboard-2.php on line 87

```
$limit = 'LIMIT'.($pn-1)*$itemPerPage.','.$itemPerPage;
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp ORDER BY emp_id $limit");

$outputList = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){ 
$id = $row["emp_id"];
$fname = $row["emp_fname"];
$lname = $row["emp_lname"];
$email = $row["emp_email"];
$desc = $row["emp_desc"];

$outputList = '
<tr>
 <td>'.$id.'</td>
 <td>'.$fname.'</td>
 <td>'.$lname.'</td>
 <td>'.$email.'</td>
 <td>'.$desc.'</td>
 <td>
 <a href="view.php?id='.$id.'" title="View details..."><img src="assets/img/view.png" alt="View" /></a> | <a href="edit.php?id='.$id.'" title="Edit details..."><img src="assets/img/edit.png" alt="Edit" /></a> | <a href="delete.php?id='.$id.'" title="Delete details..."><img src="assets/img/delete.png" alt="Delete" /></a></td>
 </tr>
 '; 
 }
 ?>
 <html>
<head>
    <title>
    Employee dashboards!!!!
    </title>
    <style type="text/css">
 .pagNumActive {
     color: #000;
     border:#060 1px solid; background-color: #D2FFD2; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
 }
 .paginationNumbers a:link {
     color: #000;
     text-decoration: none;
     border:#999 1px solid; background-color:#F0F0F0; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
 }
 .paginationNumbers a:visited {
     color: #000;
     text-decoration: none;
     border:#999 1px solid; background-color:#F0F0F0; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
 }
 .paginationNumbers a:hover {
     color: #000;
     text-decoration: none;
     border:#060 1px solid; background-color: #D2FFD2; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
 }
 .paginationNumbers a:active {
     color: #000;
     text-decoration: none;
     border:#999 1px solid; background-color:#F0F0F0; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
 }
 </style>

</head>
<body>
<center>
<?php echo $paginationDisplay; ?>
</center>   
    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="4" border="4" width="100%" >
        <thead>
 <tr>
 <th>Employee ID</th>
 <th>Employee First Name</th>
 <th>Employee Last Name</th>
 <th>Employee Email ID</th>
 <th>Employee Bio</th>
 <th>Actions</th>
 </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>    
        <?php echo $outputList; ?>
            </tbody>
         </table>
    <center>
        <?php echo $paginationDisplay; ?>
    </center>       
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: It looks like you need a space after `LIMIT`

Answer (score 0):

```
$limit = 'LIMIT'.($pn-1)*$itemPerPage.','.$itemPerPage;
```

Need a space after `LIMIT`.

```
$limit = 'LIMIT '.($pn-1)*$itemPerPage.','.$itemPerPage;
```